# Android - OnTouch repeat action

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, handler

What is the best solution if I want to make a OnTouch event repeat itself?
For example if I hold my finger on the screen I want an integer to increase by 1 until I remove my finger from the screen?

EDIT: Thanks for your replies :)
Can I do it in a similiar way for handling canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a timer, that is scheduled to run every second. Keep it running and increment your counter at each run. Stop the timer when the finger is released.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, and counting here.
`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to stop of your counter.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer of ohdroid:

You can have a `boolean` variable which needs to be set false while initializing. When the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` gets called, set it true and put your counter increment code into a an if block, which checks the boolean variable's value as condition. In `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` set the value to false again.
Code example:

```
View#setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListner(){
  int counter=0;
  boolean flag=false;
  public void onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event){
      if(event==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          flag=true;
      }
      if(event==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          flag=false;
      }
      if(flag){
          counter++;
      }
  }
});
```

**Edit:** If the above code doesn't work, then try the following which uses `AsyncTask` :

```
boolean flag=false;
RunTask task=new RunTask();
int counter=0;
View#setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListner(){
  public void onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event){
      if(event==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          flag=true;
          task.execute(MyActivity.this);
      }
      if(event==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          flag=false;
          task.cancel(true);
      }
  }
});
class RunTask extends AsyncTask<MyActivity,Integer, Integer>{
    protected Integer doInBackground(MyActivity... params) {
        while(params[0].flag)
                        counter++;
                    return counter;
    }
 }
```

Comment: But doesn't OnTouchListener only gets called when there are changes? Like if I move my finger upwords or downwords? So it won't reach the if(flag) before any movement has occoured?